# Mostrar un parametro de mi aplicacion en android con System.out.print

Tags: java, android

Hola he hecho una pequeña aplicación en android que se instala, pero ahora quería añadirle una opción para que pueda usar un dominio en lugar de una IP. Entonces para comprobar si de verdad consigo la IP de mi dominio lo que hago es:

```
System.out.println("EJEMPLO"+giriAddress);
```

El código completo sería:

```
package my.app.client;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import my.app.client.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LauncherActivity extends Activity
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        Intent Client, ClientAlt;
        // Button btnStart, btnStop;
        // EditText ipfield, portfield;
        private InetAddress giriAddress;

        public LauncherActivity()
        throws UnknownHostException
        {
            this.giriAddress=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
            System.out.println("EJEMPLO"+giriAddress);

        }   
        //private String hostIP = giriAddress.getHostAddress() ;
        private String myIp = "IP"; // Put your IP in these quotes.
        private int myPort = PORT; // Put your port there, notice that there are no quotes here.

        @Override
        public void onStart()
            {
                super.onStart();
                onResume();
            }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
            {
                super.onResume();
                Client = new Intent(this, Client.class);
                Client.setAction(LauncherActivity.class.getName());
                getConfig();
                Client.putExtra("IP", myIp);
                Client.putExtra("PORT", myPort);

                startService(Client);
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//              setContentView(R.layout.main);
                Client = new Intent(this, Client.class);
                Client.setAction(LauncherActivity.class.getName());
                getConfig();
                Client.putExtra("IP", myIp);
                Client.putExtra("PORT", myPort);

                startService(Client);
                //moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
        /**
         * get Config
         */
        private void getConfig()
            {
                Properties pro = new Properties();
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.config);
                try
                    {
                        pro.load(is);
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                myIp = pro.getProperty("host");
                myPort = Integer.valueOf(pro.getProperty("prot"));
                System.out.println(myIp);
                System.out.println(myPort);
            }
    }
```

Lo que hago es mostrarlo en mi consola pero cuando arranca la aplicación y se instala nunca me aparece mi `"EJEMPLO + IP"`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo mostrar desde mi consola esta IP, ya que nunca me la muestra en mi consola!

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente no se esta ejecutando el bloque de código ya que no se esta provocando un error:

```
 public LauncherActivity()
        throws UnknownHostException
        {
            this.giriAddress=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
            System.out.println("EJEMPLO"+giriAddress);

        }
```

Si provocas un error, entonces podrás ver que se imprime lo que deseas, por ejemplo agrega dentro de `onCreateView()`:

```
 throw new RuntimeException("Provocando un CRASH!");
```

Comment: Entonces el código que pusistes no se ejecutará a menos que de un error?, yo lo incluí ya que sino ponia el `throws UnknownHostException` me mandaba el siguiente error, `Description Resource Path Location Type Unhandled exception type UnknownHostException`. Y por eso pensaba que era indispensable, pero lo que pretendía era que obtuviese la IP de mi dominio al arrancarlo.

Comment: Si provocas un error, entonces determina que tu Activity arrojara un error tipo UnknownHostException, por lo tanto se imprimiría lo que deseas. realiza una prueba provocando un error agregando en onCreate() throw new RuntimeException("Provocando un CRASH!"); , de esta forma veras que se imprime lo que definiste.

Comment: hice eso que me dijistes `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     throw new RuntimeException("Provocando un CRASH!");`, pero no me mostro nada lo siento soy muy novato en esto disculpa de nuevo..

Comment: @OmarOmar es porque seguramente aquí   this.giriAddress=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com"); se esta provocando otro tipo de error, probablemente un NetworkOnThreadException, agrega unicamente   throws UnknownHostException
        {          
            System.out.println("EJEMPLO OCURRIO UN ERROR!");

        }    y prueba nuevamente. :)